# Xamarin WebView Teclado por cima do site

Tags: c#, xamarin, webview

Tenho um projeto em xamarin forms, com um webview dentro dele.
Ao clicar em qualquer input o teclado aparece, porem sobrepõe o input da pagina html.

alguém sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer isso no seu **App.Xaml.cs**

```
 using AndroidSpecific = Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific; 

 AndroidSpecific.Application.SetWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(this, AndroidSpecific.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85024/webview-doesnt-get-resized-or-panned-when-soft-keyboard-is-overlayed

Answer (score 0):

Bote isso no seu App.cs

```
Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific.Application.SetWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(this, Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

Comment: não resolveu, é o mesmo método da resposta acima

Comment: Botou dentro do construtor?

Comment: sim, antes do InitializeComponent, depois tambem,
Coloquei no OnStart Também